# Link to old page which already has permanent redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have an 301 redirect form oldPage.php to newPage.php in htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldPage.php$ /newPage.php
```

Now I would like forceOldPage.php to be redirected to oldPage.php (without being redirected to newPage.php)

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove your `.htaccess` redirect and instead redirect in `oldPage.php` if the referer isn't `forceOldPage.php`.

Something like this at the top of `oldPage.php` is a good start, adjust and refine as required.

```
<?php

// If the referring page isn't "forceOldPage.php"...
if ( !strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'forceOldPage.php' ) ) {
  // ...301 redirect to "newPage.php"
  header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
  header( "Location: /newPage.php" );
  die();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to assume "force" (choose any string) will not be part of the query string on any page going to oldPage.php. Use RewriteCond and RewriteRule. Then redirect forceOldPage.php to oldPage.php?force.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !force
RewriteRule oldPage.php newPage.php [R=301]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/forceOldPage.php$ /oldPage.php?force
```

FYI: I tried using HTTP_REFERER as a way to detect if user came from forceOldPage. However, the referer is not passed to new page on redirect (in my environment at least).